# Is it correct to validate fields in the following way?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I need to check required fields but with some cases. I'm trying the following:

```
var PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({});

PostSchema.pre('validate', function (next) {
   var error = new ValidationError(this);

   if (this.type === 'question' && !Array.isArray(this.tags)) {
      error.errors.tags = new ValidatorError({message: 'Tags field is required', type: 'required', path: 'tags'});
   }

   if (!Object.keys(error.errors).length) {
      return next();
   } else {
     return next(error);   
   }
});
```

Is it correct to make validation the approach above and don't it break mongoose in a future?

Answer (score 1):

Per [mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html), `Validation` is an internal piece of `middleware`. I think it is correct to make validation as you did, also I test it with following codes

```
var PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    type: String,
    tags: String,
});

PostSchema.pre('validate', function (next) {
    var error = new ValidationError(this);

    if (this.type === 'question' && !Array.isArray(this.tags)) {
        error.errors.tags = new ValidationError({message: 'Tags field is required', type: 'required', path: 'tags'});
    }

    if (!Object.keys(error.errors).length) {
        return next();
    } else {
        return next(error);   
    }
});

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

var p = new Post({
    type: 'question',
    tags: 'abc'
});

p.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('save post successfully');
});
```

As the `tags` is not an `Array`, it will trigger `validate` and error shown as below

```
{ [ValidationError: Post validation failed]
  message: 'Post validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors:
   { tags:
      { [ValidationError: Validation failed]
        message: 'Validation failed',
        name: 'ValidationError',
        errors: {} } } }
```

Since `Validation` is one internal piece of middleware, it could be OK to add it to codes, and do NOT break mongoose, only if this `Validation` middleware does NOT removed from mongoose.

BTW, in this post [Handling Mongoose validation errors – where and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012250/handling-mongoose-validation-errors-where-and-how), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17024166/3011380) also gives sort of same codes here.

Comment: Thanks, for the help!

Comment: Do you use mongoose in your projects?

Comment: @Erik, yes, the mongoose is used in my project.