# Node.js: How to get the incorrect fields in the Error object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have unique and required fields in my schema below.

An error is returned when any of them are left blank.

How do I find the paths in `Error` object with information on which fields were left blank?

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
 
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var kullaniciShema = new Schema({
    gsm: String,
    email: String,
    kullaniciAdi: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    sifre: { type: String, required: true},
}, { collection: 'kullanici' });

kullaniciShema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

var Kullanici = mongoose.model('Kullanici', kullaniciShema);

module.exports = Kullanici;
```

Below is the controller where I save submitted data into the database. Some of the incoming data is empty, so I get an error for the fields that were left blank.

How do I find the incorrect fields in the `Error` object?

```js
var yeniKullanici = new Kullanici({
    gsm: req.body.gsm,
    email: req.body.email,   
    kullaniciAdi: req.body.kullaniciAdi,
    sifre: req.body.sifre,
});

yeniKullanici.save(function(err){
    if (err) {
        //var error=new err("hata");
        //console.log(error.path);
        selectAllFromKullanici((result) => { 
            //console.log(forUsersError.length);
            forUsersError[forUsersError.length] = assert.equal(error.errors['ad'].message, 'Path `name` is required.');
            res.render("kullanicilar", { kullanicilar: result, hata: forUsersError });
        })
    } else {
        selectAllFromKullanici((result) => { 
           res.render("kullanicilar", { kullanicilar: result });
        })
    }
});
```

I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Mongoose validation errors – where and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012250/handling-mongoose-validation-errors-where-and-how)

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the fields are empty BEFORE you try to run into a failure and extract data from an error message, which may fail on unknown errors.